# Interface method is giving me a non-invokable error when called

Tags: c#, interface, invocation

So here is my interface, simplified

```
public interface ISecurityServiceInvoker
{
    string WebAppSession(string sManCo);
    Dictionary<string, string> WebAppSession();
}
```

And here is my class, simplified

```
public class SecurityServiceInvoker : ISecurityServiceInvoker
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> WebAppSession()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public string WebAppSession(string sManCo)
    {
        return String.empty;
    }
}
```

I call it like so:

```
Dictionary<string, string> cSessions = SecurityControl.WebAppSession();
```

And the error it gives me is:

```
Error   177 Non-invocable member 'x.x.WebServices.Invoker.Security.ISecurityServiceInvoker.WebAppSession' cannot be used like a method.
```

Is this the compiler thinking my method is a property because it's not a simple type like int, string etc or am I missing something else?

It works fine for the overloaded method of the same name with return type string and one input parameter!

Comment: Include the lines before and after it in your question. the problem may be there. Also, this looks like it is issue 177 in your error list. Maybe solving a earlier error will fix this error.

Comment: what is the type of SecurityControl?

Comment: @Matt it's ISecurityServiceInvoker and in the past this was a property and it was able to use it ok. It was only after I changed it to a method that it started going wrong.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain There are a lot of errors but none are related. I'm doing a huge upgrade to an enterprise system I've been working on for years so I'm certain the other errors aren't affecting it.

Comment: We need more context. The code you provided as-is is fine, so the problem is not here. You need to provide more info, try to re-create the problem in a new simple project and provide that code here. In the process of trying to create a simple example of it you will often find out what the problem was and fix it.

Comment: I fixed the problem by changing it to a property by surrounding the contents of the method with get { }... maybe you can't call methods of interfaces but you can call properties?

Comment: Like I said, we needed to see the old code. Including the few lines before and after and we can explain why it was fixed.